# How do I use a Crash Report from Apple in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, binary, crash-reports

I have received a Crash Report from Apple (joy). I understand I can symbolize this report in order to see what is crashing in my code. I understand I need the dSYM and build binary to do this.

My question is what are the exact steps I need to follow in Xcode to do this? I have the build folder I submitted via iTunes connect still saved on my computer. How do I get the dSYM and binary into Xcode so that I can drag and drop the crash report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag the crash log into the Device Logs section in Xcode's Organizer window. Xcode will symbolicate it automatically if it can find the dSYM file on your disk.

Comment: Hi - thanks - I tried that but it doesnt seem to work - the crash log does display in xCode organizer but it doesnt look like it has symbolized. Any ideas ?

Comment: I saw a tweet from an Apple engineer the other day who suggested the following: if the crash report came from a Windows user, try converting the line endings from Windows to Unix format and try symbolicating it again.